# UIImagePickerController: how to take >1 photo?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been trying to build a UI that's as similar as possible to the built in iPhone 'camera' app as possible. Necessarily I've been using the `UIImagePickerController` class.

It imposes on me two constraints that I wish to overcome...

1. I'd like to be able to take more than one photo (currently mine takes one then comes to a sudden stop.
2. I wish to skip the 'photo verification' stage where the photo/movie can be vetted by the user before committing it to the photo library.

Both of these are currently beyond me, and I know they're both possible as 'ClearCam' on the store does it perfectly.

Your clues & boos are all welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wont be able to do it with `UIImagePickerController`... However, look at [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html)`. You will have much more control over the camera and its actions, and you can use it to take more than one still image at a time with no interruption.

Specifically, look at `AVCaptureDevice`, `AVCaptureInput` and the subclasses of `AVCaptureOutput`. Additionally, `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` allows you to grab images from the current camera session asynchronously... I hope this helps!